# Performance Considerations - VisualState vs Toggling Visibility using AttachedProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties, visualstatemanager, radgridview

Currently we are having a visual element in the ControlTemplate of a control whose Visibility is bound to an attached property and which is set on the control when a certain condition is met. When the attached property is true, we make the element visible (a border) and collapse it when the value is false.

Another approach is to change the state of the control by adding some custom states to it.

Considering scenarios such as a grid (for example, Telerik's RadGridView etc - the attached property is set on the GridViewCell to make one of its ControlTemplate element visible/change of state of the cell) where huge amounts of data is loaded, which method shows more performance?

Answer (score 2):

The attached property way is definitely OK. If you want to create custom visual states you will most likely end up doing the same thing - instead of creating an attached property and attach to the `GridViewCell`, you extend the control to have the same property and a new visual state where you set the `Visibility` of the `Border` to `Collapsed`, and you trigger the state when the property's condition is met.

The control `RadGridView` has built-in virtualization, I don't think you need to worry about performance at all. But I guess creating an attached property might be a little bit simpler, while extending the control might be a little big more flexible - say if you want to do some heavy animation in the new state, you can easily do it in Blend.